# phpcake HABTM users has many friends, table naming convention

Tags: php, cakephp, naming, has-and-belongs-to-many, convention

I was modeling a social networking style website where people would be able to have other people on their contacts list, i wanted to model this relationship as a HABTM relation on the Same table  User, but according to http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM i have to give create table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_users` (
  `users_users.id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `users_users.user_id` int(11) NOT NULL ,
      `users_users.user_id` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`users_users.id`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9
```

Please Help, how can I avoid repetition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For HABTM relationships that reference the same table, you need to change the name of the foreign key.   Define `users_users`, with three fields: `id`, `user_id`, and `friend_id`.

In your User model, set up the relationship, assigning an explicit foreignKey and associationForeignKey:

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Friend' => array(
        'joinTable' => 'users_users',
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'friend_id'
    )
);
```